# PLSQL TYPE modifications

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I have created the below type,

```
create or replace
TYPE          MSSINT.TEST_TYPE
AS OBJECT
(service_phone_num varchar2(15),
name_last varchar2(50),
name_first varchar2(50));
```

Now I need to change the dataype of service_phone_num to NUMBER.

Can we achieve this using the below command or something like below?

```
ALTER TYPE MSSINT.TEST_TYPE MODIFY ATTRIBUTE (service_phone_num NUMBER) CASCADE;
```

Comment: Do you have any data in the table?

Comment: What dependencies does the type have? Can you just rebuild it, or are there tables, columns etc using it?

Comment: Yes it has data..

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following:

```
create or replace
TYPE          MSSINT.TEST_TYPE
AS OBJECT
(service_phone_num number(15),
name_last varchar2(50),
name_first varchar2(50));
```

Should work, as you have `create or replace`.

Comment: Just watch out for dependencies, which already exist and use the `service_phone_num`. All-in-All you should be safe, the Database should do implicit conversion/casts for the majority of the cases, as I assume the phone number is digits-only.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command

```
create or replace
TYPE          MSSINT.TEST_TYPE
AS OBJECT
(service_phone_num number,
name_last varchar2(50),
name_first varchar2(50));
```

`Replace` modify your type.